# How to render the page after downloading all the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

In my React application there is a page with a table. There are three columns in the table and a certain number of rows (for example, 10, that is, 10 records in a table). The data for each of the three columns is obtained as a result of three different queries to the database (to different tables in the database).
As a result, when this page is loaded in the table, sometimes only one of the three columns becomes full (only one of the queries is completed), and after a reload page, the table becomes full.

At the moment I did next: for every query to the database, there is a function with a fetch query. The call of all these functions is in

```
componentDidMount()
```

How to render a page correctly only after all the data obtained from the database?

Comment: You can put in a loader and write a function that keeps checking if status of those three APIs are 200, then only remove that loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you can do something like this:

```
class MyTableComponent {
    state = {
        loaded: false
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Promise.all([this.fetchColumn1(), this.fetchColumn2(), this.fetchColumn3()])
            .then(([column1, column2, column3]) => {
                // Do whatever you want with columns
                this.setState({loaded: true, columns: {column1, column2, column3}})
            });
    }

    render() {
        // render nothing until everything is loaded (You can replace it with loading state
        if(!this.state.loaded) return null;
        else return <Table columns={this.state.columns} />
    }
```

In the future, with the help of react-cache it will be possible to do the same job very neater

```
const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading</p>}
            <MyTable />
        </Suspense>
    )
}

const getColumn1 = () => {...}
const getColumn2 = () => {...}
const getColumn3 = () => {...}
const getColumns = () => Promise.all([getColumn1, getColumn2, getColumn3])
const columnsResource = createResource(getColumns)
const MyTableComponent = (props) => {
    let [column1, column2, column3] = columnsResource.read();

    // Columns will be fetched at this point, unless this line will now execute and nearest parrent suspense fallback will get rendered
    return <Table columns={{column1, column2, column3}} />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

without code can't say much, but maybe think of implementing promises/(async/await) to make render wait for fetching all data and then display it

Answer (score 0):

After all the 3 calls to fetch data for the 3 columns are done, then only you should call the componentDidMount method. Currently it seems like with just one ajax call output you are calling this method.

My recommendation is, from UI you should make only one call to your backend layer. And from your backend code, make 3 calls to fetch data from 3 tables and return result to UI. So overall there will be only one call from UI to backend, this will enhance the performance also a bit.